# Routing doesn't work in my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails resource in my routes.rb.  I created method in the controller:

```
def test_action
end
```

and added a line in routes.rb:

```
Test2::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :todos
  resources :docs

  match "/todos/test_action" => "todos#test_action"
end
```

But when I'm trying to get ulr http://localhost:3000/todos/test_action/ I get the error message:

```
illegal ObjectId format: test_action
```

Why and how I can fix it?

Comment: Where did you put your route? As far as I remember, the earlier routes have precedence over matching latter.

Comment: Could you show the code around the `match "/todos/test_action"`?

Comment: I updated my question and include the whole routes.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would venture to say that the routing is working but whatever you're doing in (or before) the action is failing.  Check this by explicitly raising an exception in your action before anything else.  For example:

```
def test_action
  raise "In test_action with #{params.to_yaml}!"
  ...
end
```

if you do not see that exception raised, ensure there is not a before_filter on the controller that is intercepting it and throwing your error.

Once you are sure that you're making it to your action, you can start looking into your real problem which I'm assuming is related to the use of mongo based on [these results](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=rails%20%20illegal%20ObjectId%20format).